# CakePHP added column doesn't appear in query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, caching, model

I have added a `new_column` to a MyISAM table on a MySQLproduction server.

I have deleted the appropriate model cache file from the /app/tmp/models folder.

Upon reloading the page and inspection, the **newly generated cache file for the model INCLUDES the new column**.

The new column **doesn't appear in SQL queries** or results when read with fields => null.

```
debug($this->read(null, $id));
  //Query generates fields: SELECT Model.column_a, Model.column_b, Model.id WHERE ...
  //Results do not include the new column

debug($this->read(array('new_column'), $id));
  //Query generates fields: SELECT Model.new_column, Model.id WHERE ...
  //Results include the new column and id
```

Possible caveats and additional info:

- The table has 39 columns *(why would this be a problem?)*
- The model is an EXTENDED class from a plugin
- The new column definition is TEXT DEFAULT null
- Previous updates to the table gave expected results
- Local development replica of the app doesn't have this issue
- The test controller action enables Configure::write(debug => 2)
- CakePHP 2.3.6, PHP 5.4.19, MySQL 5.1.70

How to make the Model recognize the new table definition? Are there any other cache systems I should investigate?

---

**Edit #1:**

```
debug($this->ModelName->getDataSource()->describe('table_name'));
// outputs all columns
// ...
'new_column' => array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'null' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'length' => null,
    'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
)
```

**Edit #2:**

I have tried disabling the cache completely. Although the model picks up the new column, it is not really a solution.

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
// new_column appears in both query and results
```

**Edit #3:**

Further debugging shows that there is a discrepancy between these two results:

```
$this->ModelName->getDataSource()->fields($this->Model, 'ModelName');
//returns fields without new_colum
array_keys($this->ModelName->schema());
//returns fields with new_column
```

And this temporarily solves the problem:

```
$ds = $this->ModelName->getDataSource();
$ds->cacheMethods = false;
...
```

Method caching of the DboSource is the source of this issue. Slowly getting to the bottom of things.. :D

Answer (score 10):

You have to clear all the cache files (but not directories) in `app/tmp/cache` whenever you update an application that is in production (debug is set to 0).

The actual cache causing problems in this issue was the `app/tmp/cache/persistent/_cake_core_method_cache`. Don't let the *persistent* part fool you, as it did me.

See [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3118292/1346501) for more details.

Comment: How did the _persistent_ part fool you (there's no other reference to persistent in the question/answers)? Generally speaking, clearing the cache means deleting all the files under `tmp`.

Comment: I do not clear the cache so often, so I was cautious not to break any existing functionality. "Persistent" is a word that translates to "should stay where it is" in my brain. :) I also guessed that issue resides in the model, so _why clear anything else_? [the book of Caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html) might include a section about clearing.

Comment: You're my hero of the day .. I was tired of deleting models from the cache and seeing no luck .. I didn't know I have to delete files under persistent too

Answer (score 0):

It is probably something related to the Database cache engine: in this case you can solve your issue just changing the query (for example, removing a field using the 'fields' statement). You can even try deleting the CakePHP's model cache: it's located in app/tmp/cache/models.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I have deleted all files from app/tmp/cache/models, to no avail. But it is certainly a caching problem, see edit #2

Comment: As I said, have you tried changing the query adding or removing a field? This will explain if it's a query caching issue or not.

Comment: Yes, I have. I have also disabled/enabled Model->cacheQueries and tried with 'cache' query parameter. No success. The only thing that helped so far was disabling the caching at the core.

Answer (score 0):

In fact what you can add a bootstrap file if you use a Plugin.
In my global bootstrap file I put:

```
CakePlugin::load('Myplugin',    array('routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true));
```

and in Plugin/Myplugin/Config/bootstrap.php I have

```
<?php
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'prefix' => 'cake_core_myplugin_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => true,
    'duration' => '+7 days',
));
?>
```

I added two columns in one of my models and I faced the same issue has you. Then I deleted all the models and persistent cache files **and** I change the duration inside my bootstrap file to 1 min.
Finally, my model was ok and reloaded. Later I go back to the initial duration.
It is durty, but it also looks like CakePHP messed up a little bit with cache.

Hope that it can help