# CAKEPHP 2 Won't save hidden field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I made a form with a hidden field with the value of a email but the value email doesn't save in the database.

This is the form field:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('emailadres', ['value' => 'email@example.com']);
```

When I read the array $this->request->data, I see the email in the array. The column in the database has the name 'emailadres'.
This is the output of the array:

```
array(1) { ["Ticket"]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(2) "4872 ["emailadres"]=> string(24) "email@example.com" ["title"]=> string(5) "This is a title" ["department"]=> string(9) "department1" ["message"]=> string(32) "This is a message"} }
```

does anyone know why this email field is not saving to the database?

Thanks!

Comment: show your database structure

Comment: Do you want a screenshot of the table structure or SQL data?? @B.Desai

Comment: table structure

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/m03Yr4B) This is a screenshot of the table structure

Comment: Does it work if the field is not hidden? If you have altered the table recently, make sure you have cleared the cache. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111720/cakephp-why-do-some-changes-not-happen-until-i-switch-debugging-to-3

Comment: No, it doesn't work when the field is not hidden...